# iOS : Create common Singleton UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

How to create Singleton UIView for my project.

I want to use this common UIView as subview in all UIViewController so if it is singleton thats why no memory consumption are there.

Comment: No, if it's a singleton, that's because you implemented it to be one. Do you have a question?

Comment: Any other way to do the same ?

Comment: A view can only have one superview - just like there can only be one highlander.

Comment: You might want to go through this blog. http://onedayitwillmake.com/blog/2013/07/ios-creating-reusable-uiviews-with-storyboard/

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't share a single view across multiple superviews. You will need multiple instances of the view.